# How can I Improve my logic by using forEach, not for loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach

Please check my code first

I used axios.all (GET method).

```js
.then((res) => {
  let everyDataArray = [];
  
  console.log(res); // output = [ {response}, {response} ]    

  for(let i=0; i < res.length; i++) {
    everyDataArray.push(...res[i].response)
  }
})
```

Right now, I'm using for loop for combining all the responses to an array.

However, What I'm trying to do is **using forEach, not for.**

I have checked https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach ,

but still working on how. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really what you want is to use `map` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) because you want to transform one array into another.

To be clear, `forEach` is for the case when you want to apply a function to each item to use for side effects (like printing), rather than collecting the return values.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use map.

```js
.then((res) => {
  console.log(res); // output = [ {response}, {response} ]    
  let everyDataArray = res.map(item => item.response);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code could look something like the following:

```
.then((res) => {
  let everyDataArray = res.reduce((a,c)=>(a.push(...c.response),a),[]);
  // ...
  console.log(everyDataArray);
})
```

I used `.reduce()` instead of `.map()` as the resulting array will be of different length compared to the input array.